# SQL/PHP: Show top 3 most sold/viewed products images from database in slider of website

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query I am using

```
select
   sum (order meta . order qty) as total,
   product.p pic as pic 
from
   product 
   join order meta 
      on product . p id = order meta . p id 
   join order meta 
      on product . order meta id = order meta . order meta id 
group by
   order meta .p id 
order by
   total desc limit = 3;
```

but this is not working.

NOTE: I am new to stack.. and while adding table names.it gave me an error.. so i gave space in my table names...else there is no space in my table names. :D :D

These are tables

1. product = p id/p title/p desc/p pic/p qty/p price/p date.
2. order = order id/amount/discount/status/payment gateway/date.
3. order meta = order meta id/order order id/order p id/order qty/order user id/amount.

Comment: If a table or column name contains spaces, you need to put the name in backticks.

Comment: And if you join with the same table multiple times, you need to give them aliases so you can distinguish them.

Comment: heya :) thank you for helping .. I am new to stack.. and while adding table names.it gave me an error.. so i gave space in my table names...else there is no space in my table names. :))

Answer (score 0):

You need backticks around table and column names that have spaces. You need to assign aliases to the tables that you join multiple times. And there's no `=` in the `LIMIT` clause.

```
select
   sum(om2.`order qty`) as total,
   product.`p pic` as pic 
from
   product 
   join `order meta` AS om1
      on product.`p id` = om1.`order p id` 
   join `order meta` AS om2
      on product.`order meta id` = om2.`order meta id`
group by
   om1.`order p id` 
order by
   total desc 
limit 3;
```

I'm not sure why you're joining with `order meta` twice, though, since you don't seem to use anything from one of them in the `select` list.

Comment: Heya Mr Barmar.... i am getting an error while running your sql query                             here its is : "#1630 - FUNCTION ddbshopping.sum does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual "

Comment: You can't have a space between `SUM` and `(`

Comment: Thank you sir :)) ,,.. for your so fast response.......... Now its giving this error     "#1054 - Unknown column 'om1.pid' in 'on clause"                  :((

Comment: You had the wrong column name in your query. `p id` should be `order p id`.

Comment: Sir, i think this query is wrong.. cause when i correct one thing it gives me an another error .... so can you please help me with it.. with the database table data I provided..???

Comment: You need to show some sample data and the expected results. Like I said in my answer, I don't know why you're joining with the table twice, that's probably causing the wrong results.

Comment: Sir, basically i need to find the most purchased products image from my database and use them in the slider of my website. this is the only thing I need :) :)  thank you sir :D

Comment: I asked you to post some sample data and the desired result. If you want my help, you'll do what I ask.